# Как сделать рассылку из телеграмм канала в бот (чтобы последний пост можно было переслать авторизованному в боте пользователю)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

как сделать рассылку из телеграмм канала в бот (чтобы последний пост можно было переслать авторизованному в боте пользователю). Есть

> bot.forward_message(message.chat.id...)

и надо сделать, чтобы сразу после публикации сообщение пересылалось в бот, но как это реализовать? Искал в что-нибудь методах telebot, вроде как ничего... В многопоточность лезть не хочется...

Comment: А при чем здесь вообще многопоточность?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с multiprocessing

```
import telebot
import time
import datetime
from multiprocessing import *
import schedule
telebot.apihelper.proxy = {'PROXY'}
API_TOKEN = 'API'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
 
 
def start_process():#Запуск Process
    p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=()).start()
 
    
class P_schedule(): # Class для работы с schedule
    def start_schedule(): #Запуск schedule
        ######Параметры для schedule######
        schedule.every().day.at("11:02").do(P_schedule.send_message1)
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(P_schedule.send_message2)
        ##################################
        
        while True: #Запуск цикла
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
 
    ####Функции для выполнения заданий по времени  
    def send_message1():
        bot.send_message(USER_ID, 'Отправка сообщения по времени')
    def send_message2():
        bot.send_message(USER_ID, 'Отправка сообщения через определенное время')
    ################
 
###Настройки команд telebot#########
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Нажали start')            
#####################
 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_process()
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except:
        pass
```